# Tomcat remote debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am really stuck with **Tomcat remote debugging with eclipse**.

I tried almost everything but I get **Failed to  connect to remote vm. connection refused**. I tried  by *changing port, creating .bat* file and many more. I am having eclipse kepler and installed tomcat through eclipse only. Have created a spring MVC project and want to debug remotely. Can anyone give a detailed solution from *changes in line no. of catalina.bat to* *creation of any new file*?

Comment: Is there a tutorial or guide you're following?

Answer (score 0):

check iptables setting!!!

add  debug port pass!!!

-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT